# Problemas com strings copiadas de uma planilha

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, codeigniter

Tenho um sistema que usa o framework CodeIgniter, esse sistema tem alguns campos que o usuário usa para cadastrar coisas... O usuário copia algumas frases que são padrão de uma planilha do Libre Office, e esses dados que o usuário cadastra são cadastrados no meu sistema, e através de um Web Service é cadastrado em outro sistema, o problema é que a Frase Aparece lá tudo certo tipo: "Copo Descartável Preto", mas quando vou usar uma parte do sistema que serve para procurar algo que foi cadastrado de acordo com essa frase o sistema não Reconhece os espaços em brancos e eu não consigo pesquisar o cadastro que foi feito.

Sei que as planilhas do Libre Office usam a codificação UTF-8, nossos sistemas e arquivos que temos usam a codificação "ISO 8859-1", então tentei usar uma solução que era decodificar a Frase para outra codificação, mas não deu certo e as vezes aparece um erro falando que estou usando um caratê ilegal, veja logo abaixo o que eu tentei fazer:

```
function decodeStringAuto($str, $decode = 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSIT') {

  $str = iconv(
      mb_detect_encoding($str, mb_detect_order (), true),
      $decode,
      reduce_multiples($str, ' ', true)
  );

  return $str;
}
```

Já tentei várias alternativas que procurei na internet mas não consegui resolver o problema, alguém tem uma alternativa para isso ?

Comment: Os dados do usuário do libre office vem através do ctrl+c // ctrl+v ou o sistema importa o arquivo libre e lê os dados ?

Comment: Quando insere "Copo Descartável Preto", como fica o saída antes e depois dessa sua função? Coloca um exemplo da string com os erros diferentes.